# cakePHP hosting not pointing to links

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have hosted my new website here http://cvspforcomval.site90.net/ which is a free hosting site. The problem is that I can't see the pictures in my slide, and when I enter to the navigation links I get an error.

I have changed the default webroot/index.php to:

```
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', DS.'home'.DS.'a3503999');
}

if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', 'app');
```

and my directory goes like this
/root/
    public_html/  <---webroot
    app/
    lib/

I'm just wondering if using the free hosting site affects the error. Or I just missed something out.

<---EDITED Added below--->
In my shared hosting site. I have setup folder in this way

```
/app
/public_html   <---webrooot
/lib
```

I have the default htaccess in my public_html which is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

My suspicious is that i need to change my .htaccess. I haven't solved it yet

Comment: Did you tested in your local host?

Comment: its working properly in my localhost.

Comment: Problably is the version of php

Answer (score 0):

i am getting page not found error which is due to the anchors. You are not using proper ctp links.You have to create the anchors as

```
$this->Html->link(__'My Page',array('controller'=>'Home','action'=>'name_of_action'));
```